# I have to click twice to make it work, scroll or click event

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewPager that has 6 pages and in each page there is a `PullToRefreshGridView`. 
I found that I have to click twice to triggered the click event or scroll the GridView.
The first click didn't triggered the click event.
These 6 pages have the same situation.

Please can someone help me to debug and tell me what am I doing wrong here.

This is my code:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```

and MyPagerAdapter is:

```
public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 6;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object o) {
            Log.d("DESTROY", "destroying view at position " + position);
            View view = (View) o;
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView(view);
            view = null;
        }

        // Returns total number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS; 
        }

        // Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) 
            {
            case 0:
                return TypeZero.newInstance("", "Page # 1");
            case 1:
                return TypeOne.newInstance("", "Page # 2");
            case 2:
                return TypeTwo.newInstance("", "Page # 3");
            case 3:
                return TypeThree.newInstance("", "Page # 4");
            case 4:
                return TypeFour.newInstance("", "Page # 5");
            case 5:
                return TypeFive.newInstance("", "Page # 6");
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        // Returns the page title for the top indicator
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch(position)
            {
            case 0:
                return "Zero";
            case 1:
                return "One";
            case 2:
                return "Two";
            case 3:
                return "Three";
            case 4:
                return "Four";
            case 5:
                return "Five";
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
```

here is my layout activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#556fa5"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#f44336"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:tabTextColor="#03A9F4" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The `PullToRefreshGridView` layout as below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.handmark.pulltorefresh.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- The PullToRefreshGridView replaces a standard GridView widget. -->

    <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.PullToRefreshGridView
        xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/pull_refresh_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        ptr:ptrDrawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        ptr:ptrMode="both" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the layout file?

Comment: Have you set focusability to false to any of the views or the parent layout?

Comment: Problem can be that you are requesting requestfocus on any view on the layout. Please check for the same in the layout file.

Comment: @BaluSKT:I have added my layout

Comment: @RageshRamesh: I have already tried to set focusable and focusableInTouchMode to false, and it not work.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong place. Show the layout file that contains the gridview and buttons

Answer (score 0):

Please try this before setting the adapter.

```
viewPager.invalidate();  
viewPager.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it not wok.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I add

```
main_layout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

at every activity of `gridview` inside the `viewPager`.
This one cause the focus `false`.